# StyleCop for ReSharper

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, coding-style, stylecop

I like stylecop and we use it to enforce coding standards.

I dont like the fact that there is no way to automatically fix problems. So was thinking of making a plugin. Once I realised that 2010 is better for doing this I backtracked.

I've been looking for an existing tool to help automate this process and have come across stylecop for resharper. http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/

Has anyone got any positive/negative experiences of using this plugin

Comment: I've never heard anyone say they liked StyleCop before. I find it is more of a hate/respect relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use it for about a year now, and I found it to be quite stable. It slows down things a little bit (like every plugin naturally does), and it can be somewhat annoying, if almost everything is underlined during typing, but generally speaking, I found it to be a valuable coding help...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the StyleCop for Resharper to very good effect. Coupled with the clean code feature of Resharper it helps in organizing the code and improve the quality by enforcing the standards.

If you are serious about improving the quality of code, I would suggest making StyleCop for Resharper a part of your daily life.